# TFS policy - prevent check-in when code is not custom guidelines compliant

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, commit, policy

In our organization we use TFS 2018 and Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

As far as I got until now, there is a way "client-side", configuring from Visual Studio, selecting Team\Team Project Settings\Source Control\Check-in Policy\Code Analysis and I should the custom ruleset defined.
[image]

I need two things:

1. Set a custom guideline that is mix of both default Microsoft ones and other tools' guidelines, like Roslynator or StyleCop.
2. Create a custom policy server side in order to prevent check-in from Visual Studio (or whatever client we can think of) if code is not compliant to those guidelines.

For the first point, I'll make a clear simple example.
[image]
There are the guidelines embedded in Visual Studio.
But they are not complete and I would like to extend them, taking stuff here and there or defining new ones from scratch.

I want to use e.g.:

- CA1500: Variable names should not match field names (from default Visual Studio Managed Binary Analysis)
- RCS1145: Remove redundant 'as' operator (from Roslynator)
- RCS1204  Use EventArgs.Empty (from Roslynator)
- SA1302: InterfaceNamesMustBeginWithI (from StyleCop)
- SA1305: FieldNamesMustNotUseHungarianNotation (from StyleCop)

How can I do it? And can i do it without make me define it at project level (like incorporating stylecop file for every .csprj) but more at least at solution or Team Project level?

For the second point, I already defined the compulsory comment and compulsory work item attached.
And I can even define new policies, it's true, but they can all be overridden client side.

Is it possible to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this is two part:

1. Educate your users to configure the right policies and editor settings. Creating custom project templates and distributing those can help (or deploying a custom build target onto the machine which enforces good defaults.. Having a good local policy will help people do the right thing and people who are supported to do the right thing will likely not try to get around that.
2. Setup a CI build for your projects. VSTS and TFS have a nice feature which will run a build whenever code is changed. You can even set it up as a Gated Checkin build which will check the sources before they're checked in. This check happens on the server and is much harder to by-pass. You can also configure the build to always override the code analysis settings, even if they're not configured in the project. My [MsBuild Helper tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-msbuild-helper-task) will help you setup the right MsBuild properties to do that.

As to your more specific questions:

- You cannot setup Code Analysis Rules at the Team Project level without also configuring the ruleset for all Visual Studio Projects. Otherwise the checkin policy will cause the check-in to fail, but the developer will then still have to update all projects in the solution with the right ruleset.
- You cannot prevent people from by-passing the local check-in policy. The best you can do is to use Reporting Services and Alerts to detect the breach of policy and take corrective action.

Comment: Pretty clear infos thx, but I don't understand how to use your extension. I clicked on your wiki but still I'm puzzled.
Is there a how to/manual? Where the screenshot comes from?
Visual Studio or TFS?

Comment: TFS / VSTS. You can plug in the extension in the new build pipeline, set the Code Analysis ruleset to the one you want to use (including a path to a custom one if you want to use that). Then pass the output variable into the Visual Studio Build or MsBuild task in the Additional Arguments textbox.

Comment: I've installed the extension in TFS 2018 but now...what I'm supposed to do?
Should I add a specific task in the build pipeline? And what that would be?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could add the Rule Set into TFS source control and then select it from Code Analysis Policy Editor. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

2. Check-in policy is already applied to a team project, not a single project.
3. To edit check-in policy, you must have the **Edit project-level information** permission. You could deny this permission for the users to prevent them from editing the check-in policy.